# Setting bytes-to-inode ratio on AKS storage class

Tags: azure, storage, aks

I'm hitting inode limits on an AKS cluster in a volume (ext4) provisioned with Azure Disk Provisioner.

I've found the docs on the [CSI Driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/azuredisk-csi-driver), but there's no mention on how to choose the target filesystem or formatting options.

How can I choose the filesystem used or the options given to the mkfs command (like setting the bytes to inode ratio on ext4) on creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it seems to be impossible to directly influence file system formatting options, changing the filesystem to another *is* possible:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd-xfs
parameters:
  fsType: xfs # <------
  skuName: StandardSSD_LRS
provisioner: disk.csi.azure.com
```

This alleviates the inode exhaustion issue somewhat.